# Control if a field is unique in a django form

Tags: django, forms

First error :I want to check if group_name field value is unique in a modelforms
I tried this code but seems not working as if i put a new value in this field, there is no message but data as not been add to table

Second error: i nether have any message. Maybe, I should not redirect pages ?

my code in views.py:

```
def group_create(request):
    group_form = GroupForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        group_form = GroupForm(request.POST)

        if group_form.is_valid():
            group_name = group_form.cleaned_data.get('group_name')

            if Group.objects.filter(group_name=group_name).exists:

                messages.error(request, 'this group already exists')

            else:
                group_form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Group created')

        return redirect('group_list')

    return render(request, 'imports/group_create.html', {
        "group_form": group_form,
    })
```

my model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupParent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Code pour message type toaster -->
            {% if messages %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">

                        <ul class="alert" role="alert">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <p {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
<!-- fin messages -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 sidebar">
             {%  block sidebar %}{%  endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 content">
                {% block heading %}{% endblock %}
                {%  block page %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Normally the `Form` itself will check that, so no need to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Django's [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) already validates the uniqness of fields that you marked [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique), as is specified in the [documentation on *Interaction with model validation* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#interaction-with-model-validation):

> (...)
>
> The model's `clean()` method will be called **before any uniqueness
>   checks** are made. (...).

If the field is not valid, than it will add that error to the [**`group_form.errors`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors). The reason why you did not see those is that you, regardless whether the form is valid or not, just redirect to a view, and thus the form is discarded.

If you render the form accordingly, it will add extra messages to the fields with errors:

```
def group_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        group_form = GroupForm(request.POST)
        if group_form.is_valid():
            group_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Group created')
            # only in case of success
            return redirect('group_list')
    else:
        group_form = GroupForm()

    return render(request, 'imports/group_create.html', {
        "group_form": group_form,
    })
```